# condition to check string size in a python fuction

Tags: python

I have a df which I need to transform column from object to string and then count how many characters each string has. So I made a generic function shown below:

```
def get_cpf(cpf):
if cpf.astype(pd.StringDtype()).str.len() == 11:
    return 'CPF'
elif (cpf.astype(pd.StringDtype()).str.len() < 10 or cpf.astype(pd.StringDtype()).str.len() > 14) or (cpf.astype(pd.StringDtype()).str.len() > 11 and cpf.astype(pd.StringDtype()).str.len() < 13):
    return 'Sem identificacao'
else:
    return 'CNPJ'
```

When I apply the function in my df it returns the following error:

```
df['check6'] = get_cpf(df['CPF_ou_CNPJ'])
```

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16256\4021734166.py in <module>
----> 1 df['check6'] = get_cpf(df['CPF_ou_CNPJ'])

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16256\2308362031.py in get_cpf(cpf)
      1 def get_cpf(cpf):
      2    # cpf = cpf.fillna('0')
----> 3     if cpf.astype(pd.StringDtype()).str.len() == 11:
      4         return 'CPF'
      5     elif (cpf.astype(pd.StringDtype()).str.len() < 10 or cpf.astype(pd.StringDtype()).str.len() > 14) or (cpf.astype(pd.StringDtype()).str.len() > 11 and cpf.astype(pd.StringDtype()).str.len() < 13):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1536     def __nonzero__(self):
   1537         raise ValueError(
-> 1538             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1539             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1540         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how `pandas` handles the `len` function internally, however if you already convert the cell to string why don't you just call the `len` on it like this:

```py
def get_cpf(cpf):
    cpf_length = len(cpf.astype(pd.StringDtype()))
    if cpf_length == 11:
        return 'CPF'
    elif (cpf_length < 10 or cpf_length > 14) or (cpf_length > 11 and cpf_length < 13):
        return 'Sem identificacao'
    else:
        return 'CNPJ'
```

Comment: TypeError: Expected an instance of StringDtype, but got the class instead. Try instantiating 'dtype'.
Return this error.

Comment: Maybe you need to convert *cpf.astype(pd.StringDtype)* to str?

Comment: So, but the function astype should be transform, correct?

Comment: Yeah there was a typo, try it with `pd.StringDtype()` or with just `str`

Comment: I saw your edit now, but don't work :(